# How To Get Cell Return Data From Various Cells Based On Two Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get J39 to return the text listed in G26 based on the conditions of D38 matching with what is listed in column B (In this example D38 is "Carol Young" and that value is found in B26) and J38 matching D2 (Call #1). It was suggested that I use IF VLOOKUP to do this but I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my form]

Comment: A search for "excel vlookup" will give you several useful source of information on using `VLOOKUP`

Comment: You've mentioned _"..Based On Two Conditions"_    || Name is one.. what is the other condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula :IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$2000,D38)*(J38=$D$2)>0,G26,"").I anchored cell D2 reference because I assumed that was a Column label.